# Unitary Equivalent of Derivative in Fourier Space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

It is known that for $L^2(\mathbb R)$ the operator $Tf(x) = if'(x)$ is unitary equivalent to $\hat T \hat f(\xi )= \xi \hat f(\xi) $.
Where domain of T is $H^1(\mathbb R)$.
Hence the Spectrum of T in this case is $EssRan (M_{\xi})=\mathbb R$

(EssRan $M_{\xi}$:=  Essential range of multiplication by $h(\xi)=\xi$). Here $\hat T = M_{\xi}$

But in case of bounded domain (say $(0,1)$).
If we consider $T'f(x) = f'(x)$, $D(T')=H^1(0,1)$.

The function $\phi (x)= e^{xz}$ satisfies $(T-zI)\phi=0$ for any $z \in \mathbb C$

Hence Spectrum of $T'$ is all $\mathbb C$.

It is clear that $T'$ is not unitary equivalent to multiplication in fourier space ($\{\hat f(n)\}_{n\in Z}\rightarrow \{n \hat f(n)\}$).

I need to know what is unitary equivalent operator of derivative in this case.(It is certainly not multiplication, then what it is?)

Comment: If you choose the proper space (namely $H_0^1((0,1))$), then $T'$ will be unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $\xi$ (if I don't miss any subtle points at the moment). So part of the problem is choosing the proper domain of definition. You need to know that $T'$ with domain $V\leq L^2$ is self-adjoint. Only in this case the spectral theorem implies that $T'$ is unitarily equivalent to some multiplication operator on some space. Apart from this: What exactly do you mean with "what is unitary equivalent operator of derivative in this case"? The derivative is certainly equivalent to itself:)

Comment: @PhoemueX I meant to ask that there is a unitary map between $L^2(0,1)$ to $L^2(\mathbb Z)$. As in case of $L^2(\mathbb R)$ taking derivative of a function is unitary equivalent to $\hat f(\xi)\rightarrow \xi \hat f(\xi) $ in Fourier space. But in finite domain $L^2(0,1)$ derivative is not equivalent to $\{\hat f (n)\}\rightarrow n\hat f(n)$. (I gave the counterexample). So the question was what is unitary equivalent to derivative in Fourier space if not this multiplication.

Comment: Yes, but your counterexample only works because the functions $e^{xz}$ are not in $H_0^1((0,1))$ or at least in the space $\{f \in H^1((0,1)) \mid f(0) = f(1)\}$, for $z \notin 2\pi i \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I choose the domain $H^1(0,1)$. As there is a Unitary equivalent space ($L^2(\mathbb Z)$) there must be a unitary equivalent operator corresponding to derivative in this domain $H^1(0,1)$. I do not know what it is. It is certainly not multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T = i\frac{d}{dt}$ on $H^{1}(0,1)$. The restriction of $T$ to a linear subdomain is selfadjoint iff that subdomain is equal to the follow for some real $\alpha$:
$$
        \mathcal{D}(T_{\alpha})=\{ f\in H^{1} : f(0)+e^{i\alpha}f(1)=0 \}.
$$
The only significant case (the others can be reduced to this case) is $f(0)=f(1)$, or $\alpha=0$. The restriction $T_{0}$ of $T$ to periodic functions in $H^{1}(0,1)$ is selfadjoint with an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{ e^{-2\pi inx}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$. This operator is unitarily equivalent to multiplication on $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ by $m(x)=2\pi x$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.

If you do not impose conditions on $T$, then the resulting operator has spectrum $\mathbb{C}$, and cannot be unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on any $L^{2}_{\mu}(\Omega)$ because $T$ is not normal.